# 未ログイン時のメッセージのメッセージ：「エリア５１」

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求, 完了

未ログイン時に、質問にアクセスした場合のメッセージ（エリア５１）が以下のように表示されます。stackoverflow を知らない利用者が見た時に、怪しいサイトと判断されかねないと思います。ベータ期間中の一時的なものかとは思いますが、メッセージの変更を検討すべきかと。

[image: 未ログイン時のメッセージ]

Comment: 開発者と今確認中です。英語やエリア51のサイトを理解し辛い可能性があるため、早速対応したいと思います。

Comment: yoshiさん、他のストリングがあったため、下記の回答を編集しました。問題ないと思いますが、念のため確認ください。

Comment: 確認しました！バッチリだと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現在のメッセージを変えることができます。

現在の文言：

> Warning: this site is currently in **private beta** for at least a few more days.
>
> ログインするには、エリア 51 のサイト提案にコミットし、招待メールを受信する必要があります。電子メールの招待リンクをクリックして、ログインしてください!

提案：

> このサイトは**プライベートベータ中**のため、アクセスができません。
>
> ログインするには、招待メールを受信する必要があります。電子メールの招待リンクをクリックして、ログインしてください!